# how to redirect http://www to https://www - nginx

Tags: redirect, nginx, https, no-www

I'm going to redirect `http://www.example.com` to `https://www.example.com`. in nginx server-block I have below snippet:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name www.example.com example.com;
return 301 https://www.$host$request_uri;
```

}

In case `example.com` it works properly and redirects `http://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`, but in `http://www` it doesn't redirect properly and redirect the browser to `https://www.www.example.com`. How can   I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [$server_name](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) instead of `$host`, example:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```